# How to tell if idc file was used?

Tags: device-firmware

I have an IR touch frame device which I have to configure using the `idc` file, however I am not sure if it is used at all.

I have changed the device type to `pointer` which should show a cursor on the screen when operated, and it is not happening.

From `dmesg`:

```
[   76.937599]  [0:          khubd:   40] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[   76.952845]  [0:          khubd:   40] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1ff7, idProduct=0013
[   76.952907]  [0:          khubd:   40] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   76.952955]  [0:          khubd:   40] usb 1-1: Product: FC49WH00DL-CT-B2-10P
[   76.953002]  [0:          khubd:   40] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Touch Device
[   76.953045]  [0:          khubd:   40] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 1000
[   76.969757]  [0:          khubd:   40] input: Touch Device FC49WH00DL-CT-B2-10P as /devices/usb.25/ff600000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input5
[   76.976113]  [0:          khubd:   40] hid-multitouch 0003:1FF7:0013.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v2.00 Mouse [Touch Device FC49WH00DL-CT-B2-10P] on usb-xhci-hcd.0.auto-1/input0
```

The file I've created is: `/system/usr/idc/Vendor_1ff7_Product_0013.idc`.
How can I make sure the file will be used?

Is it enough to reconnect the device to "reload" the changes in the file, or would I have to reboot the device?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify by this command: **adb shell dumpsys input**. This will list out all your input devices supported. In the dumpsys output look for Configuration File under Event Hub State->Devices->Go to your device name. Here you find your answer. For me it works.

Answer (score 0):

My `idc` file was not used due to incorrect file permission.

The owner has to be `root` and the permissions need to be `644`.
With this the file is picked up on each reconnect of the device.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Link](https://lynxbee.com/how-to-identify-which-idc-file-used-by-input-device-in-android) , once you push the IDC File either using VID/PID or using device name, then you can look for "ConfigurationFile" parameter in the output of adb command "adb shell dumpsys input" for your device. You should see your IDC File in "ConfigurationFile" with complete path.

ConfigurationFile : /system/usr/idc/Vendor_1ff7_Product_0013.idc

as in your case.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like you're affiliated with the website. While it's okay to refer to a web managed by yourself, take note that *explicit disclosure is required on the post itself*. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).